# is there a way to add token info to the solana devnet like on the mainnet?

Tags: token, blockchain, solana

I want to test our token incl. naming, icon, price etc. on the Solana Devnet but was only able to find the token-list PR which is currently only available for the Solana mainnet (as far as I can tell)

Can someone tell me if there's a "token-list pull request" on the devnet or an alternative way to handle that, pls.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a new token for devnet only, you can put in a normal token addition pull request, but you'll have to specify `"chainId": 103` for devnet.  This is defined at [1], and you can see all of the current devnet tokens at [2].

[1] https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/c1ff0ac267d03397f56a7030b02d357f90d49f79/src/lib/tokenlist.ts#L5

[2] https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/c1ff0ac267d03397f56a7030b02d357f90d49f79/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json#L7513

Answer (score 0):

As Jon pointed out, you need to make a PR to [solana-labs/token-list](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list).

However, the repository has been archived, so this method no longer work.

In the README you will find latest instructions to update the token metadata.

You can also use this tool https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/ to update your token metadata on devnet.

Here is a screenshot of my Phantom wallet after updating token metadata:
[image]